# PayPal API refunds through PayPal plugin on WordPress / WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, e-commerce

I am currently using the current PayPal plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-payments/

I have used the PayPal API to render more than one PayPal button on a page as the above plugin does not allow you to do this.

After the PayPal transaction is approved, it runs a PHP function that creates a WooCommerce order and fills in the data from the PayPal transaction such as the refund ID  and setting the correct payment gateway etc. This all goes through great, but when it comes to refunding with the above plugin it fails.

I have compared the CSV files from both the API implementation and standard checkout process and both seem to be bringing in the same data.

I have done a bit of research and it seems that if an order is placed through checkout with the plugin, it creates its own order id, which may link back to the correct refund ID from the transaction. I have contacted their plugin support, but they have been unable to tell me.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When that plugin creates an order, an invoice_id and custom_id are set on [these lines in the code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-paypal-payments/blob/7caecef8d99ecafa37aae42757217ca879351584/modules/ppcp-api-client/src/Factory/PurchaseUnitFactory.php#L122).

The invoice ID is later used [when doing a refund](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-paypal-payments/blob/5fb4a39ec9f454fd8f4e2f98933d0c310a564034/modules/ppcp-wc-gateway/src/Processor/RefundProcessor.php#L119).

If you backtrack through that code doing the refund, it first makes use of a GET API call to the PayPal Order endpoint, [which happens within here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-paypal-payments/blob/5fb4a39ec9f454fd8f4e2f98933d0c310a564034/modules/ppcp-wc-gateway/src/Processor/RefundProcessor.php#L82).

I highlight the particular line where this GET call depends on some meta information with the PayPal Gateway Order ID.

---

As an aside, this refund process is not well implemented by this WooCommerce plugin. Refunds are ultimately done using a capture ID, and should *not* rely on the Orders endpoint being accessible to provide a GET response that includes that capture ID. It works well enough so long as the PayPal Orders endpoint retains a record of that Order ID (which is not forever, as it's not an accounting value), but this is wrong to rely on. Instead, the Capture ID (eq. to the PayPal transaction ID) is what should be stored at transaction completion/capture time (as meta), and *that* stored meta value can then later be directly used to use the v2/payments refund, with no GET API request to the Orders API endpoint. The Orders API endpoint is only meant to be used during checkout approval, it is incorrect to be relying on it for anything once an order capture is successfully completed.

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer, thanks!

May I add some code to the thread for you to take a look at please?